# Google Search Console and Page Speed Insights crawlers don't load page consistently

Tags: web-crawler, single-page-application, google-pagespeed, google-crawlers, pagespeed-insights

We have been struggling with Page Speed Insights and Google Search Console loading our webpage consistently. It is an Angular SPA without SSR (server side rendering).

When I run a speed check of our website, sometimes it gives an expected score of 60-70 (mobile) and it displays our website properly rendered in the image. But other times, it returns perfect 100 (mobile again) but displays only the bit of our page that we include in the original HTML, without any JS executed at all. I attached both images below.

It seems that the issue is that sometimes it does not wait for the JS to render the page and assumes that the page is fully loaded.

Therefore, I have several questions here:
- How do these crawlers decide when a webpage is fully loaded?
- How do we ensure that Google Crawler always sees the content we intend it to see?

I understand that SSR might be the only solution that guarantees it, but it is very frustrating to keep getting the hints from people at google that SPAs are supported, but then keep finding new evidence that the support is pretty buggy.

[image: Loaded webpage]
[image: Not loaded webpage]

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question, but I do know that the build-in chrome tool gives more reliable results. Besides that I would suggest using other page speed test tools alongside them (to get an avarage) and think of what your actual goal is. Is your goal to actually increase the sitespeed? Or is your goal to get the reporting tool to report a good sitespeed to have some kind of KPI satisfied?

Comment: @CularBytes my main goal now is for google crawler to see the contents of the webpage. This is way more important than the score from any tool

Comment: are you sure you aren't getting any errors, I am guessing you would be using requireJS or similar mechanism. It could be hundreds of different issues here, care to post a public URL so I can do a bit of digging for you?

Comment: It loads fine most of the time (close to 100%) as it is served from a CDN. It sounds like the issue is related with `googlebot` not bothering to spend enough time to run the `js` and receive `xhr` responses to actually render the page. The public URL: `https://www.eldorado.gg`. Many thanks for the help

Comment: Same here, since 2 or 3 weeks. Looks like a general problem in Pagespeed Insights.

Comment: @Adrian, does GoogleBot scrape you well though? Idk that much about PageSpeedInsights, but googlebot not seeing our content is bad

Comment: @eddyP23 Similer behavior like yours. Most of the times it works, sometimes 99% but the screenshots shows that Google is missing something. And lately I got errors before it even starts doing something.
This just started about 2 or 3 weeks ago. Before that, it almost always worked. (maybe it is somehow related to the latest pagespeed update included in search console??) (btw. we don't use angular, just WordPress with some theme, so just SSR)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you are experiencing is due to your chat widget. (I believe, impossible to know for sure)

The page loads and then after an amount of time (around 5 seconds) it seems to load the chat widget JS etc. (this may be intentional for performance).

However what Lighthouse (the engine behind PSI) does is wait for CPU idle and network idle to calculate your score.

Not sure of the time on network idle but CPU idle is looking for 5 seconds of 'quiet time' as part of calculating when the `First CPU Idle`, `Max first input delay` and `time to interactive` occurs (mainly `First CPU idle`).

I would guess that depending on network latency etc. sometimes that full 5 seconds elapses giving you a great score, other times the widget starts loading within the 5 seconds and so it takes it into account.

The most accurate way to get your score is to use Chrome Audit and change to 'Applied Slow 4G, 4x CPU Slowdown' as the `simulated` one can amplify behaviours like this one.